# How can I specify what AD site a PC should join?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have a PC in an active directory domain which is not receiving GPO updates to install software.

The PC was added to the domain last night, and I had expected it to use the AD GPOs to install software automatically, but even gpupdate /force is not providing the software consistent to our GPOs.

I have verified the PC is a member of the domain, and is found within AD Users and Groups, it is also a member of groups specified by the GPOs, and it displays our domain-name in its' configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sites and services displays two different subnets, and the PC of interest has an IP in the one I wish it to.

However, this issue was brought about because the GPM was not applying software to this machine even though it had identical groups to other PCs which it was.

We determined that the PC was identifying itself as a member of the correct domain in its properties, but the policies were not being applied to it as they should be, and I was seeking how to determine if it was in another site.

This issue has been resolved by adding a 'SiteName' entry to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters with the site-name specified.

Answer (score 2):

Can you run GPRESULT /R on the local machine? Is the GPO that installs the software listed? from the details in your question it looks like it is a Computer policy that you have applied so the GPO should be listed under the computer section of GPRESULT.

Also at what level have you linked the GPO? makes sure the computer itself (not the group) is in scope. By that I mean that it is in an OU where the GPO is linked or that inherits the GPO from a higher level.

Also don't forget that even if your run GPUPDATE /FORCE the application might not be installed until the PC reboots

Finally don't link GPOs to the site level, they work but it takes longer to process. link GPOs to the domain and OU levels. It then shouldn't matter which site the PC is in which is decided based on its IP Address.

To find the site a PC is in you can use NLTEST /server:Servername /dsgetsite

more info here: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/23/pstip-get-the-ad-site-name-of-a-computer/

You don't really tell a PC which Site to join, its site is determined by the IP Subnet it is on. This IP Subnet will match an IP Subnet associated with a site thorough tools like AD Sites and Services.

Hope this helps,

Mike.

Comment: *When I run GPRESULT /R on the local machine, the GPO that installs the software is listed under;
COMPUTER SETTINGS > Applied Group Policy Objects > Policy of interest

. *Your second point, I believe to be asking if the OU which the computer belongs to inherits this policy;
The computer is in a group which inherits this policy

*I have used an elevated CMD prompt, run 'gpupdate /force' and restarted a number of times to verify without success.

*I believe that the PC in question may not be a member of the site this is being applied to, and am curious how I can verify and change it.

Comment: Hi Kyle, if you go to Active Directory Sites and Services, go to the IP Subnets section and you will see a list of all subnets and the sites they are associated with. You can then match this with the Subnet the PC is in. Is this GPO inked to the site level? has the software been deployed other PCs?

Comment: Hi Again I have adjusted my answer to include using NLTEST to find the site a computer is in, if that's all you needed (how to find the site) is the questions answered?